# Are there public testnet rpc nodes?

Tags: rpc, tzscan, public-node

Recently alphanet-node.tzscan.io has turned off.
I'm looking for some public testnet nodes for development purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Testnet formerly known as "Alphanet" is now called "Babylonnet".

Public node address:

https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net/

Future Testnets will get the name of the actual protocol.
More Infos [here](https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/test_networks.html)

Answer (score 0):

The list of current testnets for the Tezos blockchain can be found at:

https://teztnets.xyz

The platform also exposes RPC services.